# Is it not necessary for electrons to move to create a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, magnetic-moment

We have been taught about diamagnetism and paramagnetism on basis of the bohr's atomic model in our school. However, we know that electrons actually do not go in complete circles or tracks, they exist as a cloud of probability around the nucleus, however these substances show magnetic interactions without their electrons "flowing" around. So, is it not necessary to be a current to produce a magnetic field?

Comment: Quantum Mechanics is tricky.  You have to double-check all of your assumptions and then check them again.  

For p and d orbitals, there is orbital angular momentum.  This seems to imply that there is motion of the electron around the nucleus.  

For s orbitals, there isn't orbital angular momentum, so what does that mean?    

So, like I said, tricky.

Comment: @DavidElm To a great extent it is safer to assume that both of those, and not to forget mentioning; spin - have no physically intuitive representation. They merely are, solely as quantized properties of the electron. It is indeed tricky.

Answer (score 6):

It is not necessary for them to move. Even an electron at rest has a magnetic field. This is related to its intrinsic angular momentum or “spin”. It is not actually spinning like a little ball, and this magnetic field cannot be understood as arising from a current.

Comment: In that case does the proton see the electron set up a current in its rest frame or does it only see the spin magnetic moment? Or does understanding this require some QED?

Comment: @Charlie My answer isn’t talking about an electron in an atom. It’s talking about an electron, by itself, at rest.

Comment: Do protons also exhibit any property as such??

Comment: @AmeyDeshpande All fermions do, so yes.

Comment: @StianYttervik I’m not sure if neutrinos have been confirmed to have a magnetic moment. If they have one theoretically, I think it is probably very small and comes from the effect of charged virtual particles, not from the neutrino “itself”.

Comment: @g. True. Might be a too strong statement, but I like stuff that categorizes. Of the fermions of such a mass where we are able to measure a magnetic moment, all have one. Protons certainly.

Answer (score 3):

According to maxwells equations only current is able to cause a magnetic field, but you if you are describing electron's properties in term of quantum mechanics you should use the following formula for the " electron's current":

[image]

And by pure chance this formula gives the same result as the simple Bohr's model.

Comment: I am amazed that many results are same by *pure chance* between Bohr's model and Quantum Mechanical model, For instance, this result as you mentioned and also the fact that the maximum probability of finding the electron in 1s orbital is exactly equal to the Bohr's radius, etc. So, is there no reason behind these coincidences whatsoever?

Comment: @AbhinavDhawan  Of course there is a reason. The Bohr model described successfully the spectra of the hydrogen atom. Any more elaborate theory **had** to reduce approximately to the Bohr model, because it had to describe the same data, the spectrum. This is true in various mathematical ways for all theoretical models of physics, since the models are built in order to explain the data, and in the region of overlap their predictions and fits should mathematically overlap.

Comment: @anna v is it  somewhat like quantum mechanics reduces to newtonian mechanics in macroscopic world...?

Comment: This current will only describe the orbital contribution to the magnetic field. It totally ignores spin.

Comment: @AbhinavDhawan this "pure chance" is actually a great symmetry of the Coulomb potential—the one that leads to degeneracy not only in magnetic quantum number $m$ (that arises from rotational invariance), but also in orbital quantum number $\ell$, as well as to all bound classical trajectories being closed when radiation is neglected.

Comment: @AbhinavDhawan in a sense yes. When dimensions become large one is in the classcial range